# Visual Studio 2015 Master Page jQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2015

I have a MasterPage that looks something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" runat="server">

    <head runat="server">
        ...
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        ...
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form2" runat="server" autocomplete="off" >
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a page that looks something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="cphHeader" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $get('<%=txtDueDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="Server">
    ...
</asp:Content>
```

When the page is displayed, we are getting a `$ is not defined` error because jQuery is not defined at the time it is called. It is generating the Child scripts before the includes with the source looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $get('<%=txtDueDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        });
</script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

This was not an issue with VS 2013.

Comment: You probably want to wrap your datepicker in a [$( document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

Comment: Were you call the include datepicker?

Comment: @delliottg he's already doing that. `$(function() {});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @dave good point, it's been a long day...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it seem like you include your `datepicker.js` before `Jquery.js` include, if so you should reverse the order and call Jquery first.

Comment: That's my issue. My master page is in the right order but it's flipping the order. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to put all your library code in your head and any application code at the bottom of your body.

That way, your library are all loaded and if your userscript fails, it will not stop loading HTML.

So in your scenario, your MasterPage would look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" runat="server">

    <head runat="server">
        ...
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form2" runat="server" autocomplete="off" >
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </form>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would take the time to rename `cphHead` to something more meaningful but it's already the recommended practice on the web.